# How to make polygons with moving vertices?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a 2D wave simulation similar to what's done in [this tutorial](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-splash-with-dynamic-2d-water-effects--gamedev-236). The problem is, I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I was thinking of using a `CAShapeLayer` and a `UIBeizerPath` since most guides say to do something like that, but the problem with that is I can't find a way to move the individual vertices of a `UIBeizerPath` without recreating the path entirely, which seems a bit performance-intensive to me.

Is there a better way than this?

Also, I don't need help with the actual wave part, I've already tried coding it before in an app called Codea with success. I just need to know the best way to draw the polygon.

Any answers will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the vertices in a `CGPath`or `CGMutablePath`. Thus you must recreate the complete path. But if you want animate the change, you need not to compute the path for every intermediate step. Core Animation can interpolate this change automatically.

Comment: Alright, that's what I figured, but is it performance intensive to recreate the path every time? Whatever Codea does seems to work incredibly fast, so is it perhaps using a different method?

Comment: I think creating a path costs not so much time. You can use `CGMutablePath` instead of `UIBezierPath`, which could be a little bit faster. But this is all POITROAE ;)

You should try it. If this is too slow for you, you can implement your own layer class, which is doing drawing and animation directly. But I think this is too much to start with.